# How can I add meta-data to a closure vector?

Tags: clojure

I wish to add type data to a clojure vector by adding meta data. What do I need to add to this to achieve this:

```
(def r (ref [1 2 3]))
```

Note that I want to add the meta data to [1 2 3]. Is this even the right way of doing this? I mean, should I be adding meta-data to the vector [1 2 3] to "r"?

Comment: Could you offer some context as to why you want to put type info in the meta data?  If you're trying to use polymorphism, there are better ways built into Clojure.

Comment: I want to put meta data in because I have several lists which I want persisted to different places, even though the lists have the same structure. Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be added to 'r':

```
user=> (def r (ref [1 2 3] :meta {:type "vector"}))
#'user/r
user=> (meta r)
{:type "vector"}
```

Comment: How is this different than (def #^{:type "vector"} r (ref [1 2 3]))?

Comment: I think the :meta option would not add additional metadata to the ref metadata map (e.g., about :ns, etc.). I can't answer you as regards other differences though.

Comment: @Zubair: I believe the `#^{...}` syntax is deprecated in Clojure 1.2. Use `^{...}` instead.